# Find all solutions of $\phi(n) = 4$ and prove there are no more.

Tags: number-theory

Find all solutions of $\phi(n) = 4$ and prove there are no more. 
I have found that when n = 5, 8, 10, & 12 are the only solutions where $\phi(n) = 4$. 
I also know that I can spilt up the solutions to say that $\phi(n) * \phi(m) = 2 *2$. 
I am just not sure where to start with the proof.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- Since $\phi(n)$ is a product of $p^e(p-1)$, the only prime factors of $n$ are such that $p-1$ divides $4$, that is, $p-1=1$ or $p-1=2$ or $p-1=4$.
- If $n$ is a prime power, $n=p^e$, then $p^{e-1}(p-1)=4$, which implies $p=2$ or $p=5$.
- Otherwise, $n=ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and so $4=\phi(n)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$, which implies $\phi(a)=1$ and $\phi(b)=4$, or $\phi(a)=\phi(b)=2$.

Comment: Another part of the question was to prove that there are no solutions for $\phi(n) = 14$

Comment: Does there not need to be a prime factorization for that one as well?

Comment: Since $14=7\cdot 2$, you should find a prime $p$ such that $\phi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1)=7$ for a certain natural number $k>0$...