# all integers for which $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic of order 4

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determin all integers for which $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic of order 4.

What I did:

I know that $|(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*| = \varphi(n)$ the Euler function.
but how to solve  $\varphi(n)=4$?

Many thanks.

Comment: If $n$ has a prime factor $\ge7$ then $\phi(n)\ge 7-1=6$.

Comment: There are not that many natural numbers $n$ with $\varphi(n)=4$.  All such numbers are less than $20$.  Furthermore, if $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic, $n$ is equal to $1$, $2$, $4$, $p^k$, or $2p^k$ for some odd prime $p$ and for some integer $k>0$.

Comment: All $n$ with $\phi(n)=4$ have been determined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511966/find-all-solutions-of-phin-4-and-prove-there-are-no-more), for example.

Answer (score 1):

You already know that $\#(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times=\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler-totient function. In general, I am unaware if there is any known direct 'inverse' for the Euler-totient function (whatever that means since the function is not injective). But this is an area of some research, see [this paper](http://www.insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJPAM/20005a81_22.pdf).

However, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi(n)=\infty$ and $\phi(n)$ is 'eventually' increasing (in that the function takes the same value [finitely many times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348443/the-equation-phi-x-n-has-only-a-finite-number-of-solutions)). So one would only need to test a few integers $n$. See the [table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Some_values_of_the_function) to see that $\phi(n)=4$ only for $n \in \{5,8,10,12\}$.